# react native laravel echo: can not find variable pusher

Tags: react-native, pusher, laravel-echo, pusher-js

i have imported laravel-echo and @pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native in react native but error occur:**can not find variable pusher**
please tell me solution will be thankfully

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import {
  Pusher,
  PusherMember,
  PusherChannel,
  PusherEvent,
} from '@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native';
let echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    key: "123",
    wsHost: "my-domain",
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    cluster: "mt1",
    disableStats: true,
    authorizer: (channel, options) => {
      console.log(options);
      return {
        authorize: async (socketId, callback) => {
          console.log('socketId, callback',channel,socketId, callback)
          const response = await fetch(`http://my-domain/api/broadcasting/auth`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              ContentType: 'application/json'
            },
            data: {
              socket_id: socketId,
              channel_name: channel.name,
            },
          })
            .then((response) => {
              console.log('fd',response);
              callback(false, response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log('test',error)
              callback(true, error);
            }); 
        },
      };
    },
  });
```

=============================================================================================================================================

Answer (score 0):

You must define **Pusher** to **window**

`window.Pusher = Pusher;`

Just write this line below the **import**

Comment: There is no window in react-native